# Problema al crear objeto con tinker (Laravel)

Tags: laravel-5

creé una migración de la siguiente manera:

```
public function up() {
Schema::create('partesdiarios', function (Blueprint $table{
....
```

Efectivamente, crea la tabla partesdiarios en MySQL. Pero cuando quiero crear un objeto desde tinker me devuelve un error:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'baseprueba.parte_diarios'
```

Es decir, busca en una tabla con un nombre distinto (**parte_diarios**).
Gracias desde ya.

Comment: como intentas desde `tinker` crear la consulta, nos la puedes mostrar?

Comment: Lo hago con: factory(App\ParteDiario::class)->create()

Comment: ahi noto la llamada a un modelo llamado `ParteDiario`, ya lo tienes creado dicho modelo?

Comment: si, el cual tiene una única instrucción: protected $guarded = []; . Dentro de la definición de la clase.

Comment: Puede ser que haya quedado "cacheado" un nombre de tabla anterior de esa migración? (pregunta de novato).

Comment: deberías tener dentro de el creado algo así no? `protected $table = "nombreTabla"` es decir una propiedad de tipo `private` que tenga el nombre de tu tabla como valor asignado

Comment: Con protected $table = "nombreTabla" funcionó! Sin esa variabla funcionaba en otro contexto pero evidentemente tengo un problema de como toma tinker las convenciones de nombres. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si, estoy viendo como hacerlo  jaja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent lee lo siguiente, por ejemplo tu modelo se llama:

```
User
```

Por lo tanto se asume que el nombre de tu tabla va de este modo:

```
users
```

Pero si por el contrario tu tabla, se llama

```
my_users
```

Entonces ya no es la convención de nombres que `Eloquent` estaba esperando; por lo tanto deberías dentro de tu modelo, declarar una propiedad que contenga el nombre de la tabla.

Retomando el ejemplo anterior, dentro del modelo `User` entonces debemos tener

`protected $table = "my_users";`

Ahora finalmente para el caso de tu pregunta, dentro de tu modelo `ParteDiario` deberías tener:

`protected $table ="partesdiarios";`

Aqui te dejo la referencia de la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#defining-models) ve a la parte que se llama **table names**